# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type UIViewAnimationOptions

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2

I just started programming and following a tutorial online I was unable to create this animation. Can anyone tell me why it's saying:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type UIViewAnimationOptions

and how to fix it?

```
view.addSubview(myFirstLabel)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {

    self.myFirstLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y:40 + 200)

}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: [UIView transitionWithView:self duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{  
 //code to change the image of UIButton  
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {  
 self.userInteractionEnabled = true;  
 }];  
options cannot be nil

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You may replace `options: nil` with `options: []` should make the error goes way.

Comment: Starting from Swift 2 the `UIViewAnimationOptions` is a struct that implements the `OptionSetType` protocol.  That is why you should pass an empty set like `options: []` instead of nil.

Comment: wasted a lot of time looking for the answer and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UIViewAnimationOptions is an enum backed by integers. You should pass 0. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) is the doc for the enum.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in swift 2. "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UIViewAnimationOptions'".  `options: []` works fine

Answer (score 0):

It's because `UIViewAnimationOptions` is an `OptionSet` type, not `Optional type`
`OptionSet` according to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset)

> You use the OptionSet protocol to represent `bitset` types, where individual bits represent members of a set.

it's mainly used to create a combined flag from the current flags inside the set,
in your case animation flags or types we can call them, this will give you the ability to combine options to make the final desired option, there are about **23** option, however in your case you can just pass an empty  `OptionSet` as `[]`