# error Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '() -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift

**This code:**

```
runAction(moveleft, completion: nil)
```

Gives error:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '() -> Void'

Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638488/nil-is-not-compatible-with-expected-argument-type-uiviewanimationoptions

Answer (score 13):

You should pass the parameter {}:

```
runAction(moveleft, completion: {})
```

as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201215/nil-is-not-compatible-with-expected-agrument-type-void) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is new with Swift 4 but I had to use

```
{_ in }
```

hope this is helpful to someone

Answer (score 1):

The function's `runAction` completion handler is type of `Void` which means, it **cant** pass `nil` as an argument.

To be able to pass `nil` as the argument, change the completions handler type from `Void` to `Void?`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to [`SKNode.runAction()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW2). In that case, `completion` is a closure that accepts no argument and return nothing either. It is to be executed after the action has completed.

There is a `runAction` that doesn't require a `completion` parameter. You should use that:

```
runAction(moveleft)
```