# nil is not compatible with expected argument type '() -> Void'

Tags: swift, swift2

```
SKAction.group([moveToAction, SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1.0, duration: 0.2)]), completion:nil)

}

runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2), completion: completion)
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> nil is not compatible with expected argument type '() -> Void'

Answer (score 6):

`() -> Void` is not `Optional` so it can not be `nil`.

You should pass empty closure as `completion` parameter:

```
..., completion: {})
```